# Faster command+tab switching support number choice?

Tags: keyboard, macos, window-manager, switching

Is there a faster way to switch between applications on mac using <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>??

when i open a lot of different apps opens at a time, i have to press lots of <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> to switch to purpose application.
Is there a way  to use <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>number</kbd> to switch to purpose application.

such as when i press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> , i want to switch to the sixth application , i just press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>, the command tab will focus to the sixth application.

Just like switch tabs in chrome. use <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>number</kbd>
Is there a proper way to do this???

IS there any software can do this?? or system apis can do this??

Comment: You could set up each app on a different Space & use specific key commands to go to that Space. I use Ctrl/number. Trouble with wanting the 6th app is you have to look at which is currently 6th. Using Spaces means they're always the same number, once assigned.

Answer (score 3):

[Manico](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/manico/id724472954?mt=12) is a App
Using Option + Number key to launch or switch to the target app in an extremely fast speed!

Feature List:

- Beautiful OS X Style interface
- Easy to call and easy to hide
- Support using shortcuts to switch between running apps (Faster than ⌘
- Tab)
- Support customizing apps and shortcuts (Faster than Dock)
- Support hiding the status icon to make menu bar clean

Answer (score 0):

No, but if you use the mouse you can <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> and then click the one you want with the mouse.

Comment: use mouse is quick.   but keyboard switch is better.   is there a third party software support??  or any APIS??

Answer (score 0):

You could use Automator to create services that take no input and consist of "Launch Application" [your favorite app here], and then assign a keyboard shortcut to that service using System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services.